# do you need to self quarantine if visiting san diego or los angeles?

Tags: usa, covid-19, california, quarantine

Back in January visitors had to [self quarantine for 14 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/162155/4868). Is that still the case?

The Regional Stay at Home order cited in the last SE question on the subject was [lifted on Jan 25](https://covid19.ca.gov/stay-home-except-for-essential-needs/).

This would be a trip for leisure. I was planning on renting a car, doing [Goat Canyon Trestle Bridge via Carrizo Gorge Road](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/us/california/goat-canyon-trestle-bridge-via-carrizo-gorge-road) and, in LA, maybe visiting [Scary Dairy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Dairy), seeing [Urban Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_Light) and checking out some of the beaches.

Thanks!

(I'm a Texas USA resident if that matters)

Comment: On March 9 CNN [reported](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/us-state-travel-restrictions-covid-19/index.html): *California has lifted its stay-at-home order but discourages out-of-state visitors. People are encouraged to quarantine for 10 days upon entering the state. Would-be visitors are advised by the state to call ahead for possible local restrictions ... for instance, Los Angeles County requires visitors to fill out this online travel form.* Tourism is not considerded to be "essential travel".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Direct answer**: a 10 day self-quarantine is strongly encouraged. It doesn't seem to be legally mandated anymore, since the Regional Stay at Home order was lifted on Jan 25th.

That being said,
***California Department of Public Health*** and **CDC strongly discourage** tourism or recreational travel.

From **Official California State Government** sources:  https://covid19.ca.gov/travel/

> Traveling into California from other states or countries for tourism or recreation is also strongly discouraged, and anyone traveling into California should self-quarantine for 10 days, unless quarantining is impracticable and the travel is for the sole purpose of meeting critical healthcare needs or other emergency response

**California Department of Public Health** travel advisory states: https://www.cdph.ca.gov/Programs/CID/DCDC/Pages/COVID-19/Travel-Advisory.aspx

> Non-Essential Travel [I]
>
> 1. Except in connection with essential travel, Californians should avoid non-essential travel to any part of California more than 120
>    miles from one's place of residence, or to other states or countries.
>    Avoiding travel reduces the risk of virus transmission, including by
>    reducing the risk that new sources of infection and, potentially, new
>    virus strains will be introduced to California.
> 2. Non-essential travelers from other states or countries are strongly discouraged from entering California, and should adhere to
>    the quarantine procedures set forth in Paragraph 3.
>    Blockquote
>    Quarantine Post-Travel
> 3. All persons arriving in or returning to California from other states or countries, should self-quarantine for 10 days [ii] after
>    arrival, except as necessary to meet urgent critical healthcare
>    staffing needs or to otherwise engage in emergency response.
>    Additionally, this recommendation does not apply to individuals who
>    routinely cross state or country borders for essential travel [iii].
>
> A Local Health Officer may determine if and when the situation within
> the Local Health Offficer's jurisdiction warrants measures that are
> more restrictive than this statewide order, and retains authority to
> implement such measures.

From **CDC**'s online Travel Planner tool (last updated 2020-12-31):

> People arriving from out of state to hotels and lodging entities must quarantine at that facility for at least the 10-day minimum recommended quarantine period

I'll leave you with the ***CDC's guidelines for travel during COVID-19***:
https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/travel-during-covid19.html

Comment: I would also note that the equation changes if you're already vaccinated as more and more people are in the US. Its not in the government recommendations yet but eventually the expectation is that travel will be 100% okay for anyone vaccinated.